# Отслеживание собщений в определенном канале Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Как можно сделать такую функцию в Discord боте на discord.py, которая бы выявляла сообщения отправленные в определенный канал и выполняла бы действия?
Я догадываюсь что это нужно сделать через `@bot.event` с `on_message`, но не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не включен **Режим разработчика**, то включаем:

**Настройки ⭢ Расширенные ⭢ Режим разработчика**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем, создаем функцию-событие `on_message(message)`.

Нам нужен именно определенный канал, поэтому получим его объект через `ID`:

**Правой кнопкой мыши на канал ⭢ Копировать ID**

Получаем объект канала:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(id)
```

Поскольку нам нужны сообщения, приходящие именно в этот канал, проверяем, чтобы канал полученного сообщения совпадал с нашим объектом `channel`:

*А также допишем условие, чтобы не считывались сообщения от ботов, если это нужно*

```
if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        await message.channel.send('В этот канал отправлено сообщение')
```

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(id)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        await message.channel.send('В этот канал отправлено сообщение')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```